# Apply blur effect to image programmatically

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, computer-vision, gaussianblur

I am using a background segmentation model and it provides a probability of each pixel belonging to foreground or background. I have this function that fills the background pixels with a solid color. But how can I make make them blur instead? Like what those video conferencing apps perform background blur effects.

```
  private int[] maskBackgroundColors(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    @ColorInt int[] colors = new int[maskWidth * maskHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < maskWidth * maskHeight; i++) {
      float backgroundLikelihood = 1 - byteBuffer.getFloat();
      if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.9) {
        
        //belonging to background pixels. Fill with a solid color.
        //But how to do blur instead?!
        colors[i] = Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 255);
        //colors[i] = applyBlurEffectToColor(colors[i]);
      }
    }
    return colors;
  }
```

I came up with this function that gets `colors[i]` pixel. But I don't see any changes, so it doesn't work.

```
private int applyBlurEffectToColor(@ColorInt int color) {
    // Apply blur effect algorithm here
    // You can use libraries like RenderScript, OpenCV, or custom algorithms to achieve the blur effect.
    // The implementation details depend on the specific blur effect you want to achieve.

    // Example: Apply Gaussian blur effect
    // You can replace this example with your own blur effect implementation
    float radius = 10.0f;
    float sigma = radius / 3.0f;
    float[] matrix = new float[]{
            1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f,
            2.0f, 4.0f, 2.0f,
            1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f
    };
    int width = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(matrix.length));
    int height = width;
    float sum = 0;
    for (float value : matrix) {
      sum += value;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      matrix[i] /= sum;
    }

    int redSum = 0;
    int greenSum = 0;
    int blueSum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offsetX = x - width / 2;
        int offsetY = y - height / 2;
        float coefficient = (float) (Math.exp(-(offsetX * offsetX + offsetY * offsetY) / (2 * sigma * sigma))
                / (2 * Math.PI * sigma * sigma));

        int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);

        redSum += (int) (coefficient * red);
        greenSum += (int) (coefficient * green);
        blueSum += (int) (coefficient * blue);
      }
    }

    int blurredColor = Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), redSum, greenSum, blueSum);
    return blurredColor;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To kick things off with a blur effect, you'll first need your desired source image. Once you've got that, a Gaussian blur is a fantastic option to consider.

Here's a quick rundown: A Gaussian blur smooths an image by placing a grid (called a kernel) over each pixel. This kernel has values based on the Gaussian function, which looks like a bell curve. The pixel under the kernel's center and its neighbors are averaged together, with the kernel values determining how much weight each pixel gets in the average. The outcome is a softer, blurred image.

For a hands-on approach, your solution might look something like this:

```java
private int[] maskBackgroundColors(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int[] sourceImage) {
    @ColorInt int[] colors = new int[maskWidth * maskHeight];
    
    // Define a 3x3 Gaussian blur kernel
    float[][] kernel = {
        {1/16f, 2/16f, 1/16f},
        {2/16f, 4/16f, 2/16f},
        {1/16f, 2/16f, 1/16f}
    };

    int kH = kernel[0].length / 2;
    int kW = kernel.length / 2;

    for (int y = 0; y < maskHeight; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maskWidth; x++) {
            int i = y * maskWidth + x;
            float backgroundLikelihood = 1 - byteBuffer.getFloat();
            if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.9) {
                // Apply Gaussian blur
                float sumR = 0, sumG = 0, sumB = 0;
                for (int ky = -kH; ky <= kH; ky++) {
                    for (int kx = -kW; kx <= kW; kx++) {
                        int nx = x + kx;
                        int ny = y + ky;
                        if (nx >= 0 && nx < maskWidth && ny >= 0 && ny < maskHeight) {
                            int neighborIndex = ny * maskWidth + nx;
                            int neighborColor = sourceImage[neighborIndex];
                            float weight = kernel[ky + kH][kx + kW];
                            sumR += weight * Color.red(neighborColor);
                            sumG += weight * Color.green(neighborColor);
                            sumB += weight * Color.blue(neighborColor);
                        }
                    }
                }
                colors[i] = Color.rgb((int) sumR, (int) sumG, (int) sumB);
            }
        }
    }
    return colors;
}
```

This implementation uses a 3x3 kernel, which provides a mild blur. For a stronger blur, you can use a larger kernel (e.g., 5x5, 7x7) with appropriate weights.

I hope this provides some clarity! Best of luck with your coding adventures!

Comment: Thanks. Do we definitely need the source image? I also came up with something similar (updated the question). What is wrong with that?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? 
From my point of view it just blurs your one color. As all factors in your kernel should add up to 1 you will give #FFFFFF to your function and get #FFFFFF out. Every time, regardless of your source image.

Comment: However the implementation in java is fairly slow. If you like a solution like Microsoft Teams, Zoom, etc. you should consider use the gpu and graphical programming (maybe shaders) to solve this problem.

Comment: Got it. I have to make some changes in the code to pass the source image. But colors[i] is already the source image buffer. Can't we just use that?

Comment: Yes of course. Thought you created it newly in your function because of that line `int[] colors = new int[maskWidth * maskHeight];`

Comment: Would you be able to update your answer to only use `colors[]` instead? I can't really change the signature of that function to pass source image again.

Comment: Just swap out every instance of sourceImage with colors. But remember, you should fill your colors array with the source image values before it enters your function. If you're making the colors array inside the function, it'll just have zeros, and the blur won't work.

Comment: It is filled with th source image. But the difference is it is a 1D array and not 2D.

Comment: sourceImage is a 1D array too...

Comment: I replaced sourceimage with colors[]. But the background did not get blurred. Instead it got a bit darker now! haha Anything missing?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255447/discussion-between-dennis-and-tina-j).